# What is the difference between a data lake with HDFS or S3 in AWS?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, hdfs, data-lake

I need to build a data lake on AWS, but I don't know how exactly S3 is different from HDFS. I found some answers in the Internet but I still don't understand the real difference.

I also need to know if someone has the data lake architecture of HDFS and S3 in AWS.

Comment: What is your particular use-case? Do you only use one Hadoop cluster? How does the data get in & out? Feel free to edit your question to add more details, for a more detailed answer.

Comment: I need to implement Informatica BDM in AWS and build a data lake

Comment: You might want to watch [AWS re:Invent 2018: Effective Data Lakes: Challenges and Design Patterns (ANT316) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5lkNHib7bw) and [AWS re:Invent 2018: Intro to AWS Lake Formation - Build a secure data lake (ANT396) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsiLMqg654s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HDFS** is only accessible to the Hadoop cluster in which it exists. If the cluster turns off or is terminated, the data in HDFS will be gone.

**Data in Amazon S3:**

- Remains available at all times (it cannot be 'turned off')
- Is accessible to **multiple clusters**
- **Is accessible to other AWS services**, such as Amazon Athena (which is 'Presto as a service', so you might not even need a Hadoop cluster)
- Has **multiple storage classes**, such as storing less-frequently accessed data at a lower cost
- **Does not have storage limits** (while HDFS is limited to the storage available in the Hadoop cluster)